# Monotony of $f(x)=x+x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})+1$ (Prove $f$ is strictly increasing)

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

Let $f(x)=x+x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})+1 , x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$.I am asked to find the $f(A)$.

We can easily show that $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \infty$. I also know that f is continuous. Now I am must prove that f is strictly monotonic, and in fact strictly increasing ( So it goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$).

For $ f'(x)= 1 + 2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})- \cos(\frac{1}{x})$. I don't think this can prove that however.Do I go for $f''$?Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: What is $A$ in $f(A)$?

Comment: Actually $f$ is not defined at 0, so it is not monotone.

Comment: I don't know the exact name for it in English (as I am not English at all and can't find it anywhere) but $f(A)$ is the set of values that $f$ can take for every $x \in A$, where $A= D_f$. So it's $f(A)= {y | y = f(x),  x \in D_f}$

Comment: This is the *range* of the function. If this is what you have to find, there is no need to discuss monotonicity.

Comment: Well, due to school book stating that to find the range of a function, you have to prove that it is continuous and strictly monotonic to take the limits of it, I kinda have to, although our teacher has told us that the range doesn't have a lot to do with the monotonicity.

Comment: But the function is NOT continuous as it is not defined at 0.

Comment: As $f'(0.17)=-0.0533994$ the function cannot be monotonically increasing on ${\mathbb R}$.

Comment: You don't *kinda* have to.

Comment: @eminem: if you add the condition $f(0) = 1$ it becomes continuous

Answer (score 1):

The following [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rfmc4mjubv) shows that the function extended to $x=0$ with $f(0)=1$ is continuous, and that the title question is impossible (if the domain is a neighbourhood of zero): [image]

Comment: So this proves that there is no way for me to prove that it's monotonic right?

Comment: yes, even though it is monotonic on if $|x|>1$, for example

Comment: $f'(0.175) <0$, for example, something that can be verified with a calculator while the above curve might be "doubted" (any number of mistakes may have happened).

Comment: @Ingix  I doubt calculators only a little less :)

Answer (score 0):

If we define $f(0):=1$ , then $f$ is continuous on $ \mathbb R.$

Since $ \lim_{x \to \pm \infty}f(x)= \pm \infty,$ the intermediate value theorem gives $f( \mathbb R) = \mathbb R.$

Comment: How do you implement the intermediate value theorem to prove this? I have never seen it be used that way, so sorry If my question is kinda dumb.

Comment: Actually $f(0)=1$ is the value needed for continuity